# Use regex to validate in a controller

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, api

to start of Sorry if i'm a complete and utter noob but i got the task of possibly using regex to verify inputs of users on a register page. I'm 100% back-end so i see no front end. so what my classmate told me is that i should use regex in the controller but i'm only writing API's. Is it possible to use REGEX in an API? also i tried specifying stuff in my model like

```
public string email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
```

But when i update my db and check the SQL in my db it doesn't say any of this stuff and when i send a post request with userdata it just allows me to put in anything as an email address. sorry if i didn't describe some stuff clearly i hope anyone could help me in anyway. we could just drop regex and make it full front-end checking i think but it would be nice to know how to do this for in the future. :)

Comment: the attributes should be on top of the property. not under

Comment: I recommend reading [ASP.Net MVC - Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations must come before property

```
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

In this way your validation must work

you can also use regex

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$", 
        ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
```

**Edit: Also In your Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(string email)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return success result
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: While this is the correct way to setup validation for an object/class/model it does not solve *when i send a post request with userdata it just allows me to put in anything as an email address*.  You should mention how to actually validate based on those attributes.

Comment: So I tried this before and it didn't work, but i tried again. and it still doesn't work. if i look in PgAdmin it shows me all the column info it says NOT NULL at all the stuff that i marked as "Required" but when i look at the email row it only says NOT NULL. and nothing else. any clue on what is going on?

Comment: please check my edit. I added ModelState validation example

Comment: Just a quick question, when i use regular expressions instead of lets say [stringlength] if i pass it through my controller with modelstate.isvalid will it still return an error if it doesn't comply with the regex?

Comment: Yes , you still get invalid with error message. However ı suggest you to customize error message trough annotation